# Telethon API - Why don't my api_id and api_hash refresh?

Tags: python, telethon

I've got a python project which employs the Telethon library to connect to Telegram.

I made some tests with it with my personal phone, registered in  `https://my.telegram.org/auth` and got my `api_hash` and `api_id`.

Now that the test worked, I wanted to use a different phone to put it to work, so I again went to the same page, got the new `api_id` and `api_hash` and changed only the lines in the code:

```
api_id = 0000000
api_hash = 'hashhashblabla'
```

However, when running the code again, I see the program still reads the messages received by my personal phone, not the new phone, despite already having changed to the new `api_id` and `api_hash` values.

Do you know of a reason why this happens?

Comment: you are probably using the same session as before, just delete the session files and try again

Answer (score 1):

The API ID and hash are permanent. They do not reset or refresh. They are attached to a developer account. As far as I know, you cannot change them.

The developer's API ID and hash can be used by other users. These users may be you. When you login, Telethon stores a "logged in session" in the `.session` file. It uses that to connect to an authorized account again without having to login every time.

You can login to as many different accounts (phone numbers, or even bot accounts using bot tokens) as you want with a developer's API ID and hash (even your own accounts).

The API ID and hash is completely separated from who the users who login using those are.